# Why does this method spit out the same results to different users

Tags: c#, asp.net, random, itext

So I have method that generates a barcode and label with that barcode. We have noticed that when more than one user generate a barcode at the same time they will both get the same file. I am using ASP.NET and I am hosting the application and the file on the a in house server.

```
public void trickylabel(string fnsku, string title)
{
    Random random = new Random();
    int randomNumber = random.Next(0, 100000);

    //Set barcode properties...

    code.parse(fnsku); // Text

    BCGDrawing drawing = new BCGDrawing(this.Server.MapPath("~") + "image"+ randomNumber.ToString() +".png", color_white);
    drawing.setBarcode(code);
    drawing.draw();

    // Draw (or save) the image into PNG format.
    Response.ContentType = "image/png";
    drawing.finish(ImageFormat.Png);

    Document doc = new Document(new iTextSharp.text.Rectangle(200f, 75f), 20F, 10F, 10F, 1F);
    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, new FileStream(Request.PhysicalApplicationPath +
        "\\"+randomNumber.ToString()+".pdf", FileMode.Create));

    doc.Open();

    iTextSharp.text.Image png = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(this.Server.MapPath("~") + "image" + randomNumber.ToString() +".png");

    doc.Add(png);

    //Sets pdf properties...

    doc.Add(new Paragraph(title, times));
    PdfAction action = new PdfAction(PdfAction.PRINTDIALOG);
    writer.SetOpenAction(action);
    doc.Close();

    Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
    Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=labels.pdf");
    Response.TransmitFile(Server.MapPath("~/"+randomNumber.ToString()+".pdf"));

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
Random random = new Random();
int randomNumber = random.Next(0, 100000);
```

The Random class generates pseudo-random sequence, that is based on some starting value, called Seed. If two Random instances are initialized with equal seeds they will produce equal number sequences.

When Random is created with parameterless constructor the Seed is created from current system time. If you ran a loop that creates instances of Random class you will notice that random.Next() value changes only several times per second (once per 16ms).

To avoid this you should reuse initialized Random instance (however, since you are using **ASP.Net** you will need to ensure that the calls of random.Next() are executed in a thread-safe way). Then your visitors will get different values each new random.Next(...) call.

Alternatively Random has a constructor that allows to set the initial Seed value manually. So, you can create your own algorithm of creating unique seeds for your users.

**UPDATE** Thread-safe Randomizer implementation.
Gets initialized on assembly load.

Usage: just replace `random.Next(0, 100000);` to `Randomizer.Next(0, 100000);`

```
public static class Randomizer
{
    private static Random rnd;
    static Randomizer()
    {
        rnd = new Random();
        rndlock = new object();
    }

    private static object rndlock;
    public static int Next(int minValue, int maxValue)
    {
        lock(rndlock)
        {
            return rnd.Next(minValue, maxValue);
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE** On thread safety and unpredictable results

As stated above, Random generates pseudo-random sequence. This means that each int number in this sequence has known previous and next numbers. This means that after a certain number of calls these numbers will start to repeat. The Random.Next() algorithm is designed to maximize number of unique items in this sequence.

So, what "unpredictable" means in this case? When several threads use the same variables simultaneously the logic of the algorithm becomes corrupted. In best scenario this makes sequences of same numbers occur more often. In worst scenario Random.Next() [starts to produce zero values on each call](http://o2platform.wordpress.com/2011/07/16/humm-net-random-class-is-not-thread-safe/) without any chance to recover.

More useful information about System.Random on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random.aspx).

Comment: FYI... Random() gets initialized with Environment.TickCount

Comment: @Paul Walls: Thanks! I was wondering why DateTime.Now.Ticks is changing more frequently than Random's seed. On my machine this value changes only once per 16 milliseconds, so you cannot rely on the fact that two consecutive visitors will have different Datetime.Now.Ticks. 16 milliseconds is a huge period of time to get duplicate results.

Comment: @Artemix: Regarding *"...for example you can store the Random instance in some static member"*. **Don't do that!** `Random` isn't thread-safe; if you store a single instance in a static then you'll get even stranger (ie, broken) results unless you enforce some sort of synchronisation yourself.

Comment: @Artemix I don't have more than one thread running at a time. Do I need to worry about this?

Comment: @Joe Tyman: Yes, you need to worry. In ASP.Net an assembly is loaded once and is reused for all requests your server processes. Thus the static members are common for all users (it will be reinitialized only when server is restarted). Each request is processed by a separate thread, so if several users are requesting the page simultaneously several threads may reference the static member at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

Or just use [NewGuid Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.newguid.aspx)

Comment: I agree, 100,000 seems like a lot of space for "uniqueness" but it is nothing compared to the space of a GUID

Comment: @Chris Haas: However in this case limiting GUID to barcode ID may produce more undesired matches than plain Random.Next(0, 100000) usage. Also, if you are looking for alternative random numbers source you may be interested in using RNGCryptoServiceProvider class: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rngcryptoserviceprovider.aspx

Comment: @Artemix, I agree that GUIDs should never be trimmed or only taken parts of. Since the requirement is to create something unique and a GUID only takes 32 characters (or less if you use something like `ShortGuid`) it seems like a logical choice. Randomness and uniqueness are very different and nothing about this project says "random" in any way to me.

Comment: @Chris Haas: According to this document http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4122.txt GUIDs generated by C# are of random type with the following pattern: xxxxxxxx-xxxx-4xxx-Vxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx, where x is random number and V is a number with bit layout as 10yy, where yy are two random bits. So, GUID actually has 122 random bits. As you can see you don't have any uniqueness benefit here (except for number of random bits) and you can use RNGCryptoServiceProvider instead. And yes, you can use GUID in C# as cheap randomizer (in terms of code). Unless it will be changed in future version of framework.

Answer (score 0):

If the requests are starting at the same time, then the Random numbers that are produced may well be the same as each other. Without providing a seed value, the Random constructor takes its seed based on the system clock, so it is possible for two instances to produce the same set of random values (which aren't random, they're pseudo-random).

Documentation here - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random.aspx

Try making your Random instance a static member of the class and having your method just call .Next on that member.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to save the pdf to disk?

I'd suggest saving the png image and the pdf document to a `MemoryStream`.
This might also lead to better performance, because there is less disk access.

```
public void trickylabel(string fnsku, string title)
{
    //Set barcode properties...

    code.parse(fnsku); // Text

    BCGDrawing drawing = new BCGDrawing(color_white);
    drawing.setBarcode(code);
    drawing.draw();

    // Draw (or save) the image into PNG format.

    using (var imageStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        drawing.finish(ImageFormat.Png, imageStream);

        using (var result = new MemoryStream())
        {
            Document doc = new Document(new iTextSharp.text.Rectangle(200f, 75f), 20F, 10F, 10F, 1F);
            PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, result);

            doc.Open();

            var png = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(imageStream), ImageFormat.Png);
            doc.Add(png);

            //Sets pdf properties...

            doc.Add(new Paragraph(title, times));
            PdfAction action = new PdfAction(PdfAction.PRINTDIALOG);
            writer.SetOpenAction(action);
            doc.Close();

            Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
            Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=labels.pdf");
            Response.BinaryWrite(result.ToArray());
        }
    }
}
```